# NFS Mount from Debian <-> OS X, Takes a long time to save changes

Tags: linux, mac, debian, mount, nfs

I have a debian machine that I am hosting NFS mounts from, I have one of those NFS mounts mounted on my OS X machine. When I save a file on my OS X machine, it takes up to 10 seconds for the changes to be reflected on the debian machine.

A little background, I am a web developer, and I am hosting all my code on the debian machine where I also host Apache and MySQL. I mount that NFS mount on my OS X machine, and modify the code on OS X, then refresh my browser to see the changes and it takes forever it seems like for the changes to take effect.

What is something I can do to speed up the NFS saves?

Here is my line from my exports file on debian...

```
/vmpool/nfs/code/   10.0.0.109(rw,sync,all_squash,no_subtree_check,insecure,anonuid=501,anongid=20)
```

Here is the line I use to mount that NFS on OS X

```
sudo mount -t nfs 10.0.0.121:/vmpool/nfs/code ~/Projects
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a well-known problem with OSX clients: You need to edit the `/etc/nfs.conf` on your client to contain

```
nfs.client.mount.options=[your other mount options],locallocks
```

A known-good line is

```
nfs.client.mount.options=nfssvers=3,async,tcp,rw,rdirplus,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,locallocks
```

if that is acceptable to you.

You can ofcourse also give those options at the command line:

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o nfssvers=3,async,tcp,rw,rdirplus,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,locallocks 10.0.0.121:/vmpool/nfs/code ~/Projects
```

Comment: seems a little faster, but still taking 3 seconds or more to save, any other ideas?

Comment: Depending on the OSX version, you might want to explore `fs.client.allow_async=1`